# Whitelist allowed hosts for Heroku postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a heroku app running with the postgres addon. I was wondering if it's possible to whitelist the allowed hosts. Normally this is done by editing the pg_hba.conf file, but that's not possible on heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible - Heroku don't provide access to that. They use highly complex and randomly generated username/passwords as you can see in your `heroku config` output but permit access from any host.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't use heroku postgres as a PCI-DSS compliant card data store? PCI-DSS does require access control on the storage.

Comment: @tapan Username and password is access control. Does it explicitly specify an ip-address based whitelist/blacklist?

Comment: @CraigRinger Unfortunately, yes. The card storage database has to be completely firewalled from the public network with only a whitelist of allowed IPs.